# Why is there uninitialized value in std::normal_distribution

Tags: c++, stl

Although the example in [std::normal_distribution reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/) compiled fine, I got a warning on uninitialized value in a similar code below.

```
#include <random>
void foo(double);
int main()
{
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::normal_distribution<double> norm_dist(0,1);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    foo(norm_dist(generator));
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -ffast-math -O -c foo.cpp" using gcc5.3.1 on my CentOS7.2, I got:

> foo.cpp:8:30: warning:
> ‘norm_dist.std::normal_distribution::_M_saved’ may be used
> uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
> foo(norm_dist(generator));

I thought STL had been well tested, but why does the compiler warn? Is the problem in g++, STL, or my code?

Comment: You might want to mention that this warning is not emitted with `-O0`.

Comment: Also `-ffast-math` toggles the warning

Comment: Yes, the warning is gone without -O, -ffast-math, or the for-loop.

Comment: Implementing `foo` also removes the warning.

Comment: foo() is a function implemented elsewhere and linked later.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the warning looks like a false positive (i.e. a compiler bug). I can't see any reason for that warning, at least.

Comment: You aren't using the STL here, you are using g++'s implementation of `std`, and your code is perfectly valid. So it's a "which part of g++ is wrong to be warning here" question.

Comment: If you implement foo in the same file like in https://godbolt.org/z/6axz6q the warning is also removed, which makes me think that there is some special corner case here with fast-math and the warning.